# Can I make resharper intellisense prefer properties over types?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, intellisense

I often use properties with the same name as the type, for instance

```
public User User {get;set;}
```

When trying to use this property in the class and typing in "User", the resharper intellisense will default to the type, adding the namespace to differentiate it from the property.

Is there a way to make resharper intellisense prefer properties over type?

Comment: Could you give an example of where you're trying to use it? Within the class, you'd *already* have the namespace (to make the property declaration work). When using an instance, you'd be typing `foo.User` wouldn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give an example where this fails?

I have replied down here so I can show you a screenshot of how it looks when I use it.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the screenshot, it shows exactly how I want it to behave. In my case however, given the exact same situation, the line above your line (the type User) is highlighted.

Comment: Ok, try upgrading to Resharper 6 (it's worth having!) and/or clear your resharper cache.

Comment: Clearing cache didn't work and upgrading is not possible atm I'm afraid

Comment: sigh! re-install? brutish i know